# gnunet-search returns no results for anything but 'test'

Tags: search

i installed gnunet 0.10.1 last week (i had to upgrade to debian jessie for this). i tried searching for the keyword `test` and got the following results:

```
$ gnunet-search -a0 test
May 03 10:10:51-090063 gnunet-search-2194 WARNING External protocol violation detected at fs_search.c:749.
#0:
gnunet-download -o "K2-Chogori.jpg" gnunet://fs/chk/CATJ32DFF8QCHR2I1CRULIV6QOSS51TIGK305LK2NSAKV370TG7KIVBNU8HJBK7VMR031LKQ5OMBJ4BM7LRPF58HJ8DMHMV82QSQ3DG.ISRLE14KRTAFSGMNI2F681UARK474NC8MSB96TCT9JSN03QNDN2846888LRTU8LQ21UHQO750NL97KSFGVTRCGCT5ES7FN978IAC6UO.5495341

#1:
gnunet-download -o "test.txt" gnunet://fs/chk/TOJB1NAAUVJKJAGQHRHS22N9I8VM32C0ESN4EFS836IT950E1MP7LGC5V2GE3LFO9U4BP23VQPTH8DPIOC2CONT9LM76ULVL00KAHVO.L2F28FPVHC51U52O0EV0KAFQPEFNF04M3MA1RVKQDUCTBT0EFAUOUROLOK92KJCTK3F23ROU1S98EA0ALAO6K0GFJGJF2CP23GQ12P0.4

#2:
gnunet-download -o "gnunet-test.txt" gnunet://fs/chk/FLBMHL3RDF17RH7QFQBJ5JT2RP86P8J2K9Q9PC88I8V5RNFVRQ22NFVEDISDD4NR8EMA1S998R2I3J72CCS8F4ACK7SMH627HK8AQFO.1BION6PPRC5TA47T3C33AKG9T9JKI1QPJUIDUM1MNGRQ7DVIT5VHDCELS378IDHD7RI10C5AHCG71VDL6US028TCB1GTT6FF3BNLIP8.15

#3:
gnunet-download -o "Oliven.jpeg" gnunet://fs/chk/O0STITF3KMHKH0PI7LPBVI1A4KDNI5E5H79SM527P7SKCMBBVFA32GVR7ETR6P2QP82J84EQUQR13E30BPRUF6LA8C10NJSJN76NA8G.OIJ3TD1ST3FD8O0EJV12HG3MDGB3E71N4UV4AL98H2IQCFIHF3PIF0T2NUOPDJ0CM6BGB7RJ9U32GQURLNTC1GGVEVR51KVE0IQVSSG.2958699

#4:
gnunet-download -o "Python.jpg" gnunet://fs/chk/R8E6MBBC0010ND6CSMFM38UC7EH5IRV7V3U7VA2G52F1NOC2HQ8Q7I8NFHHAPLFDTF326U685JLQI4HDNOS3MAOIBSAOI52QIIV7R1O.H0S3D4UGJVH6S9RA5PPUQHRUDI829D8FGRRTG9SVOOQ1AK686SVM90L2MC9PPLS3LBES8DAP5A20TV3JNEIL088NQEC39SEN79IK2B8.36468

#5:
gnunet-download -o "Mouse_final.mpg" gnunet://fs/chk/6DJ1GOJG6360HOHHQMK331HLICSSE16NMAE9HAPHU24J39DPF0JQRJ1HPPQG3RCBLHP3VJOHLDDVCF5BDS84F2L3JU8H74FGESS4D98.3RKCKP6JL57OB6353TVLD055Q9P0LC5OV88Q15NJAKUGHVTS43GFEIN5G7FFDGE04SHCG9BEF70R3OLQS0GS6J6FBH8CBOH64M3IQ5G.4881678
```

however when i search for other terms i get absolutely no results. for example i tried searching for `Das Kapital` as per the example in the user manual and this turned up nothing, even when i leave it searching for an hour. i guess it could just be that nobody has uploaded this book to the network. i was talking on irc to someone who said it used to be possible to search by category. for example you could search for all `jpg`s or all `pdf`s. **does anybody know if this is possible in gnunet?** i have tried

```
$ gnunet-search -a0 mp4
```

and i get no results. i'm not sure if i'm doing it wrong, or if this is just something that is not possible. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

searching for `pdf` turns up some results:

```
$ gnunet-search -a0 pdf
#0:
gnunet-download -o "A Gentle Introduction to the Art of Mathematics.pdf" gnunet://fs/chk/LLA760JDHAHJI7UP5F5PG37GPCIVFGKQ5L6F0JJR845267STE4U8H8JCJBJI7UBV4M6S0R9V1RF323D5GOAGPJ2GKKBQQDJOU2RLB20.Q77T641EB73BNC9U055QRBNEC4CQ2G547ESSFCCCL644IJ3K8GN21R57G1EHCAO2I189SC98M0IJ86DPV4HETHJNDK6RV7T630IT5SG.2624329

#1:
gnunet-download -o "Fundamentals of Mathematics.pdf" gnunet://fs/chk/EU0TNNGBFHULPE44KBMG6NVCC30R4HC4VTGC92PC9K9MKO8AOVK738L1TAAC9N05A6H014JNGC164DP5A1I2GEVN0FBHPGBO1SVCL68.VT4K869UHJTP77B42769GEDROARVODCBEQQTJ3UM3V26U3TI5F8Q6OC6LCLILC06K3CFAVVV7UBUBDLMIUKKA0LMJMJSNG3HOMMBQH0.8769524
```

it could just be that there are no `mp4`s on the network!?